# Objective-C: Linking user's input from text field to Table form from NSMutable Dictionary

Tags: ios, pointers, dictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Creating a medication application for engineering project. My problem is either in the mutable dictionary code or the pointer code. **Goal is to get values** (`names/phone numbers`) inputted by users to be stored in dictoinary and displayed in another page.

Have a table form visible, then when you select Add new information, our page has text input fields with code like this for each value:

```
  //add text fields for adding doctor information (first name)
UITextField *firstName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 90, 230, 60)];
firstName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
firstName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
firstName.placeholder = @"First";
firstName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
firstName.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
firstName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

Created Mutable dictionary to store this info in this format:

```
NSMutableDictionary *docDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[docDict setObject: @"*firstName"  forKey: @"doctorFirstName"];
```

Then I would like to display it in the prior page (List form). Could I use `this pointer` (placed into .m file for the page in which I'd like it to appear)?

```
NSMutableDictionary *firstName = doctDict [@"doctorFirstName"];
```

This pointer is built off of this format: id value = dictionary[@"doctorFirstName"];

Thank-you for any help!

Comment: what is "this pointer"?

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *firstName = doctDict [@"doctorFirstName"]; 

Is this not a pointer? Will it not show what a user has input into the text field on the 'edit' page? Thanks!

Comment: OK. It seems like you want to store the textField's text into the dictionary right? It would be [dict setObject:[textField text] forKey:@"doctorFirstName"]

Comment: Yes, so I would place that in the .m file of the page on which the text fields appear and then could I retrieve the the inputted text to appear on separate page using a pointer/outlet or is that outlet?

Comment: well is that separate page in the same .m file?

Comment: No, it's the page prior (below the stack), so a different .m file.

Comment: Well you have to find a way to pass that dictionary to the new view controller. Maybe set it as a property on the new view and then set it before you present the new view.